# Wondering 'UseState Working Logic' in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

i'm wondering the working logic of useState with if Statement.
For the specifications, i'm making in signup form's validation check function, and found useState doesn't work immediantly when it's used with if Statement.

The problem has found when i compare the confirmedPassword with password value.

- If i set comparision passwordConfirm with a previous state which is set by useState, says doesn't matches. (Looks one more type, one more State update needed)

  asdasd
- However, if i just put the exact input's value as using 'e.target.value' of input, finally the validation pass.

  /* States statements */

  ```
   const navigate = useNavigate();
   const initialValue = {
       id: "",
       name: "",
       email: "",
       password: "",
       confirmPassword: "",
       phone: "",
       phoneVerification: "",
       emailVerification: "",
     }; const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValue);


     const validateValue = {
       name: false,
       id: false,
       password: false,
       confirmPassword: false,
       phoneVerification: false,
       emailVerification: false,
     };
     const [isValidated, setValidate] = useState(validateValue);
  ```

...

```
else if (e.target.name === "password") {
const idRegExp = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{8,20}$/;
const validated = idRegExp.test(e.target.value);
setValidate({ ...isValidated, [e.target.name]: validated });
} else if (e.target.name === "confirmPassword") {
const validated = values.password === e.target.value ? true : false;
setValidate({ ...isValidated, [e.target.name]: validated });}
```

If i set 'e.target.value' for confirmPassword Validation check, then it works, cuz it's not checking the state value, but the exact current input's value.

However, as below, if i set that part as 'values.confirmPassword', then one letter is missing, less, when i console.log(values.confirmPassword).

```
   const onChange = (e) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    if (e.target.name === "name") {
      const nameRegExp = /^[가-힣]{2,4}$/;
      // test는 Boolean Return
      const validated = nameRegExp.test(e.target.value);
      setValidate({ ...isValidated, [e.target.name]: validated });
    }
```

...

```
    } else if (e.target.name === "password") {
      const idRegExp =
        /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{8,20}$/;
      const validated = idRegExp.test(e.target.value);
      setValidate({ ...isValidated, [e.target.name]: validated });
    } else if (e.target.name === "confirmPassword") {
      const validated = values.password === values.confirmPassword ? true : false;
      setValidate({ ...isValidated, [e.target.name]: validated });
    }
  };
```

Could anyone let me know the working logic of useState?
Thanks !

Comment: try `setValues((previousValues) => { ...previousValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });`

Comment: I tried that at the very first time, but that makes wrong. You can try in your local, and will find one typing is missing, when you use that code. So, that's why i'm wondering the useState's speicific operation, working way.

Comment: Add you project into a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) and put the link in your question to others to test